# What Terminal command will dump all Gconf keys and values? ie the ones seen in gconf-editor

Tags: command-line, gconf

I can output a single key-value, as per the following example:

```
gconftool-2 --get /apps/panel/applets/clock_screen0/object_type
bonobo-applet
```

How can I dump the entire gconf database? ... Key-names **and** Values

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To list all keys and values:

```
gconftool-2  --recursive-list /
```

To list all keys and values in xml format:

```
gconftool-2  --dump /
```

See [`man gconftool-2`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/en/man1/gconftool-2.1.html) for more info.

Comment: Thanks Andrew... I took a coffee-break too soon... The blurr of unfamiliar man navigation was starting to make things look like all ones and zeroes... but I manage to rally with the caffeine, and tried again and finally found the first one (at least)... and it's good you have pointed `--dump`; I might have stopped hunting, as  I'm due for anothe cuppa. :)